# How to import gdb file data into an Excel sheet

Tags: import, file-geodatabase, excel

How can I extract the data from a gdb file into an Excel worksheet? 
Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way.You can do it feature class by feature class(no hierarchy i.e feature dataset) as below 
[image: GDBTOExcel]

Comment: To add on to msi_g 's answer. You can read .dbf files in Excel, and re-save it as an excel file after following the steps laid out.